# Atom exclude node_modules folder from search

Tags: git, atom-editor

How to exclude node_modules folder from Atom searches "Find in project" after you have put node_modules inside your .gitignore file? Does atom require that the project actually has a git repository, or should the .gitignore be enough for Atom to exclude the folder?

My .gitignore looks like this:

```
.DS_STORE
*.log

node_modules

dist
coverage
```

Answer (score 91):

Steps

1. Launch atom
2. From the menu: edit > preferences *(atom > prefernces on Mac)*
3. From the side menu, click the button "Open Config Folder"

Now a new atom IDE should open.

1. Open the file "config.cson"
2. Add `ignoredNames: ["node_modules"]` under `core`

Example of a `config.cson`

```
"*":
  core:
    ignoredNames: [
      ".git"
      "node_modules"
    ]
  editor: {}
  minimap:
    plugins:
      "highlight-selected": true
      "highlight-selectedDecorationsZIndex": 0
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This way, `node_modules` disappears from the tree-view.

Comment: No, `node_modules` will stay with this solution. This should be the accepted answer, for sure.

Comment: A tiny detail: in my Windows version of Atom, the _Open Config Folder_ button is in File -> Settings

Comment: @sager yes, it disappears from tree view. And it's fkn annoying!

Answer (score 54):

In the "File/directory pattern" field of the search use an exclamation mark followed by the name of the directory you want to ignore:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, seperate with a comma to exclude multiple folders  f.e. !node_modules, !bower_components

Answer (score 43):

If your .gitignore file sits higher in the directory than where you are performing a *Search in Directory* your node_modules will not be excluded from Atom's search.

For that reason I recommend adding *node_modules* to the Ignored Names list in the Core Settings.

[image: Atom Editor Ignored File Names]

Answer (score 24):

The .gitignore file should be enough for Atom to exclude the folder, as long as you have the ignore "exclude VCS ignored paths" option checked.

You should also append a "/" after node_modules

```
node_modules/
```

[image]

Comment: Works on Windows, but not on Ubuntu through Virtualbox. I did what you suggested, and didn't work. It still searches from the whole project

Comment: is there a way to have node_modules show in your side bar but not on your searches?

Comment: If you're banging your head with the above not working, ensure your `.gitignore` file is in the root of your repository and not within say `/web/.gitignore`. Took me some time to realize that it only looks at `/.gitignore/`

Comment: One problem with this approach is when one has sources in a  "lib" subfolder. I agree it is not a good practice, but it happens (e.g. python + nodejs project)

Comment: Also note that if your project starts in the parent directory of the repo, .gitignore is then NOT in the root of the project so it will not be respected. Change your project to start in the root folder where the .gitignore is.

Answer (score 1):

For new versions of Atom (I am using 1.28.2 on Windows) I accessed config.cson via `File > Config...`

Then, as mentioned in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052893/5486116),  `ignoredNames: ["node_modules"]` must be added under the `core` section:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "no"
    themes: [
      "one-light-ui"
      "one-light-syntax"
    ]
    ignoredNames: ["node_modules"]
```